# Facebook Graph API rate limit for search queries

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit, rate-limiting

I'm working on a project to process a list of email addresses (around 4M entries), and determine whether they have an associated facebook account or not. I'm using graph API search query to detect that. Now is there any chance I'll get a rate limit, or even is there any official rate limit for that? Considering the list is really large and maybe we'll do multi threaded requests I'm worried about any rate limits.

I heard about un-official 600 request / 600 seconds but haven't seen any proof of it in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook finally shared their official rate limits: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting